# Issue with creating a sendable data extension via fuel SDK C#

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, fuel-sdk

I keep getting the error, "The SendableSubscriberField field cannot be blank", even though my SendableSubscriberField is not blank

here's my  code:

```
ETDataExtensionColumn deField = new ETDataExtensionColumn();
deField.FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text;
deField.Name = "PrimaryKey";
ETProfileAttribute subAttribute = new ETProfileAttribute();
subAttribute.Name = "Subsciber Key";            

var de = new ETDataExtension
{
    Name = queryName,
    CustomerKey = queryName,
    CategoryID = 10330,
    IsSendable = true,
    IsSendableSpecified = true,                                
    SendableDataExtensionField = deField,
    SendableSubscriberField = subAttribute,
    Columns = new[] {
        new ETDataExtensionColumn { Name = "PrimaryKey", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text, IsPrimaryKey = true, MaxLength = 100, IsRequired = true },
        new ETDataExtensionColumn { Name = "Account", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text },
        new ETDataExtensionColumn { Name = "FullName", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text },
        new ETDataExtensionColumn { Name = "AppStartDate", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text },
        new ETDataExtensionColumn { Name = "Email", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text },
        new ETDataExtensionColumn { Name = "FirstName", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text },
        new ETDataExtensionColumn { Name = "LastName", FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Text }},
};
var DEs = new[] { de };
var createReturn = myclient.CreateDataExtensions(DEs);
```

Comment: hey! this is for salesforce marketing cloud.  I'm using the fuelSDK for C#.  I'm just trying to create a sendable data extension.

Comment: I think the subAttribute.Name is miswritten, should be 'Subscriber Key' with the r.

Comment: wow...can't believe i didn't catch that.   I'll give that a try thank you.